# How to generate Response XML using Webservice Request?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am building a whole new webservice  application using SOAP, java and JBOSS FUSE. I have a request xml and xsd..

Can we guess the response xml by just referring to the request and the data elements?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot guess exact response, if you could what is the point of calling, you could guess response schema from WSDL that SOAP webservice publishes

Comment: yes... that's what even I was thinking... but I don't have a webservice built yet.. I just have a xsd file and a request file...

Comment: you need to [walk through it once](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html)